# Understanding _findfirst and _findnext

Tags: c++, windows, findfirst

Need to understand how _findfirst and _findnext works with pattern inputs.

I used to following code to analyze their functionality but the results confuse me.

```
    intptr_t handle;
    struct _finddata_t fblock;
    int count = 1;
    char pattern[] = "*";
    printf("Pattern is %s",pattern);
    if((handle = _findfirst(pattern,&fblock))>0){
        printf("\nfound : %d :: ",count++);
        printf("%s",fblock.name);
        while(_findnext(handle,&fblock) == 0){
            printf("\nfound : %d :: ",count++);
            printf("%s",fblock.name);
        }
    }
    printf("\ncompleted");
    //getch();
```

The results :
I have four files in the folder.

```
1.ReadMe.txt
2.ReadMe1.txt
3.ReadMe1.txt_bck
4.ReadMe1.txtbck
```

Now,

```
Enter pattern :*.tx
Pattern is *.tx
completed
```

Ok. There are no files with ext tx

```
Enter pattern :*.txt_
Pattern is *.txt_
completed
```

Ok. There are no files with ext txt_ also

```
Enter pattern :*.txt
Pattern is *.txt
found : 1 :: ReadMe.txt
found : 2 :: ReadMe1.txt
found : 3 :: ReadMe1.txtbck
found : 4 :: ReadMe1.txt_bck
completed
```

??? I asked only for ext txt. Why is txt_bck displayed?

```
Enter pattern :*.txt*
Pattern is *.txt*
found : 1 :: ReadMe.txt
found : 2 :: ReadMe1.txt
found : 3 :: ReadMe1.txtbck
found : 4 :: ReadMe1.txt_bck
completed
```

Now what is the diff between this and prev?

```
Enter pattern :ReadMe?.txt
Pattern is ReadMe?.txt
found : 1 :: ReadMe.txt
found : 2 :: ReadMe1.txt
completed
```

Expected "?" wildcard would match exactly one character but it matched 0 also.

```
Enter pattern :ReadMe*.txt
Pattern is ReadMe*.txt
found : 1 :: ReadMe.txt
found : 2 :: ReadMe1.txt
found : 3 :: ReadMe1.txtbck
found : 4 :: ReadMe1.txt_bck
completed
```

_

Comment: It works like [wildcards do](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true) on the command line.  Cast in stone roughly 45 years ago, do not assume it is regex syntax.  The oops you have to watch out for are the legacy DOS 8.3 filenames, sadly still enabled out of the box, they turn .txtbck and .txt_bck into .txt

Comment: You have buffer overflow because `sizeof(pattern) == 2`, but even with this fixed I can confirm this weird behavior.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was going to say "45 years" is hyperbole - but CP/M was first released in 1973 which is 43 years ago (and rounding to nearest 5 years is reasonable).

Comment: Not Gary Kildall's idea, it is older.  Afaik it came from DEC, somewhere around RSX-11 or RT-11.

Comment: So 8.3 filenames is the cause. Thank you.